# need help in fetching mutiple values from table

Tags: jquery, html, elasticsearch

i am creating a web page and so for that i have created two check boxes one sorts the values while the other filters the features[it fetches the values according to specifications that are provided in the box]. Individually it works fine,but when i try to use them both at the same time the features filter doesn't work

coding:

```
    var priceRangeFunction = function () {
        $(".priceRange").on("click", function () {
                countPrizeRange=countPrizeRange+1;
            var priceSortFrom = $(this).attr("from");
            var priceSortTo = $(this).attr("to");
            conditions.push({
                    "range": {
                        "items.price": {
                            "gte": priceSortFrom,
                            "lte": priceSortTo
                        }
                    }
                });
            console.log(conditions);
            search(0,conditions,featureConditions,customConditions);

        });
    };

    var priceRangeCustomiseFunction = function () {

        $(document).on('click', '#submitCustom', function (){
                countPrizeRangeCheck=countPrizeRangeCheck+1;
            var customPriceFrom = $("#custom").val();
            var customPriceTo =$("#custom2").val();
            customConditions.push({
                    "range": {
                        "items.price": {
                            "gte": customPriceFrom,
                            "lte": customPriceTo
                        }
                    }
                });
            console.log(conditions);
            search(0,conditions,featureConditions,customConditions);
            return false;

        });



    };


 Dine-O var featuresFunction = function(){
        $(".featuresList").on("click",function(){
            countFeatureRange=countFeatureRange+1;
            var featureName =[];
            featureName.push($(this).attr("value"));
            console.log("featureName" + featureName);
            featureConditions.push({
                "terms" :{
                   "items.hotelDetails.features": featureName,
                    "minimum_should_match" : 1
                }
            });
            search(0,conditions,featureConditions,customConditions);

        });
    };
```